# Canvas mouse position e.offset not working in Firefox

Tags: jquery, css, html

I'm playing around with a HTML5 game and I want to have the mouse position controlled by the canvas not the page.

I'm using `e.offsetX` and `e.offsetY`, which works as it should in Google Chrome, Safari but not in Firefox.

I'm not sure what the problem is. I have given the canvas tag `position: relative`.

Here is my [code](http://cssdeck.com/labs/azav8qki).